# Map doesn't get displayed Google Maps API V3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Code with V3 API.

```js
function initialize ()
{
    if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) 
    { 
        var ch = new GLatLng (0,0);

        var myOptions = {
            zoom:7,
            center: ch,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);

        directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(map, document.getElementById("map"));
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);                  
    }
}
```

Code with V2 API.

```js
function initialize ()
{
     if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) 
     { 
         map = new GMap2 (document.getElementById("map"));
         map.setCenter (new GLatLng(0,0),1 );
     }
}
```

The V2 API code worked flawlessly, the V3 API code is NOt displaying any map.
What's the point that I am missing?

**EDIT**
Modified the V3 code as follows, but still no maps:

```js
var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng (0, 0);

var myOptions = {
    zoom:1,
    center: chicago,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Make sure you are loading the correct Google Maps API, that you have a div tag with an id of map, and (for good measure) that you give the div a height and width.  (Perhaps better to put the height and width in a stylesheet, but for clarity, I'm including it inline here.)

Here's a web page with your post-edit code.  Try it.  Works for me.

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Google Map test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map" style="height:500px;width:500px"></div>
<script>
var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng (0, 0);

var myOptions = {
    zoom:1,
    center: chicago,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Ray @wong2 Finally this IS solved, I couldn't have done without all your help! The problem was this line `<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;key=GOOGLE_MAPS_KEY"` I replaced it with Trott's line `src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"` and this did the trick :mad: Thanks to all for their help.

Comment: Worked for me. Was not setting height and width. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In V3, all the names have changed. For example, `GLatLng` is now `google.maps.LatLng`. You will need to revise your code to use the new names.

A [link to the docs](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/basics.html) in case you don't have it

Comment: Thanks but that didn't change anything :( Maps are still not displayed!

Comment: Alright I just threw `if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) ` statement altogether, still no change. I actually want this property: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#DirectionsRoute Is it available on V2?

Comment: maybe a dumb question, but are you certain that document.getElementById("map") is actually finding a DOM element?

Comment: and it is true that `GBrowserIsCompatible()` doesn't work with V3 API. If I enable it no map gets displayed.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `GLatLng` in v3, change it to `google.maps.LatLng`

```
center: chicago,
```

Comment: I tried that too, didn't help :( this doc shows it without quotes too: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial.html#HelloWorld

Comment: @AnishaKaul: can you make a jsfiddle? (jsfiddle.net), then I can know more about your case

Comment: center needs to be a LatLng object, not a string, so changing it to "chicago" will not help. Fortunately, OP seems to have gotten that part right in subsequent edit of question.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same symptoms, my v2 maps would not display with V3. When I look in the browser console logs, I'm seeing the error: Uncaught ReferencedError: GBrowserIsIncompatible is not defined.

Per the [Google V2 to V3 Migration Guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/v2tov3#obsolete_code), GBrowserIsIncompatible is no longer supported. I haven't found an alternative and just removed the logic related to this function. This [site suggests just removing the function](http://www.mywebexperiences.com/2013/03/05/migrate-google-maps-from-v2-to-v3/).

I found other problems with migrating which are addressed in the Google Migration Guide link above.

Answer (score 0):

1- ensure your google map API key is correct.

2- it's may be not enabled in your google map console.

3- wrongly enabled the location API instead of the map API.