# ASP.NET Google Maps API v2 working, not v3

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps

I have been trying to add a map (and markers) on a google map into a asp.net web app, and got it working. Then I found out I was using GMap API v2 and not v3.
I then created the map again in v3, but now it won't show.

This is my v3 code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize() {
        var homeLatlng = new new google.maps.LatLng(57.048909, 9.921521); //McDonald's

        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 10,
            center: homeLatlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

And the v2:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function initialize() {
    if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
        var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
        map.setCenter(new GLatLng(57.05, 9.92), 14);
        map.setUIToDefault();
    }
}
</script>
```

I am sorry if this is a duplicate post, but I weren't able to find an answer to this through searching.

Kind regards,
Mowinckel

Comment: I tried following the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6176622/map-doesnt-get-displayed-google-maps-api-v3?rq=1
Didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have typo `new new`. Here is how I use.

```
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    // Load google map
    google.load("maps", "3", { other_params: "sensor=false" });

    function initialize() {
        var homeLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(57.048909, 9.921521);

        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 10,
            center: homeLatlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), 
           mapOptions);
    }

    google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);
</script>
```

### Solution for Original Question

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize() {
        var homeLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(57.048909, 9.921521); //McDonald's

        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 10,
            center: homeLatlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
<div id="map-canvas" style="width: 300px; height: 300px">
</div>
```

Comment: Tried literally copying in what you wrote, but no luck :( The javascript is placed in the masterpage and the div itself is in a content-page, if that information has any validity?

Comment: I tested your code too. It works after fixing typo `new new`. I updated the answer.

Comment: It helped using pixel based sizing. I'll worry about the responsiveness later. Thanks! :)